# tiles:insertAttribute throwing exception

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to build an application having nested tiles.

**tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" 
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.defination" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Ashoka Travels"/>
<put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

        <definition name="transportBody" extends="base.defination">
                <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/transportMain.jsp" cascade="true"/>

        </definition>

        <definition name="booking" extends="transportBody">
                        <put-attribute name="bookingRadio" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/bookingLayout.jsp" cascade="true"/>

        </definition>

        <definition name="transportBodyHeader" extends="booking">
                <put-attribute name="HeaderBookingTypeSelect" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTypeSelect.jsp" cascade="true"/>
                <put-attribute name="BodyTransportSelector" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTransportSelect.jsp" cascade="true"/>
                <put-attribute name="FooterTransportSelectorBooking" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTransportSearch.jsp" cascade="true"/>
        </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**bookingLayout.jsp**

```
<body>
<div id="transportBookingLayout">
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="HeaderBookingTypeSelect"/></div>
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="BodyTransportSelector"/></div>
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="FooterTransportSelectorBooking"/></div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is **transportMain** page which includes another JSP page through `<tiles:insertAttribute>`:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainTransport" style="border:1px solid red">
        <div id="ticketBookingDiv" class="bookTicket" >

             <%-- <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/hello.jsp" flush="true"/> --%>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="bookingRadio"></tiles:insertAttribute>
        </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringMVC] in context with path [/Travels_SpringMVC] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/transportMain.jsp at line 32

29:         
30:         
31:               --%>
32:         
33:         
34:       
35: 


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'bookingRadio' not found.
```

Comment: which view are you trying to display ?

Comment: transportMain is in body attribute of layout(main layout). transportMain is a layout itself and it have bookingRadio attribute which is including "booking" an another layout. Whenever i am running it is throwing an exception "bookingRadio"not found. So to answer your question transportMain will be displayed which include "bookingLayout.jsp"

Comment: transportMain is a jsp, I mean what is the logical view name ? Because transportBody  declare a bookingRadio but doesn't put any attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
**nested Tiles is working fine.Here is the solution.**
**tiles.xml**<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.defination" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Asoka.com"/>
<put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

        <definition name="transportMain" extends="base.defination"  >
                <put-attribute name="body">
                    <definition template="/WEB-INF/jsp/transportMain.jsp" name="mainTransport" extends="transportMain">
                        <put-attribute name="bookingRadio">
                            <definition template="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingLayout.jsp" name="layoutBooking" extends="mainTransport">
                                <put-attribute name="HeaderBookingTypeSelect" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTypeSelect.jsp" cascade="true"/>
                                <put-attribute name="BodyTransportSelector" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTransportSelect.jsp" cascade="true"/>
                                <put-attribute name="FooterTransportSelectorBooking" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/primaryPage/bookingTransportSearch.jsp" cascade="true"/>   
                            </definition>
                        </put-attribute>
                    </definition>
                </put-attribute>
        </definition>


</tiles-definitions>

**transportMain.jsp**

<form:form commandName="transportBookingForm" modelAttribute="transportBookingForm">
    <div id="mainTransport" style="border:1px solid red">
        <div id="ticketBookingDiv" class="bookTicket" >
            <tiles:insertAttribute  name="bookingRadio"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form:form>
**At Controller level**

@ModelAttribute("bookingTypeSelect")
    public ModelAndView booking(@ModelAttribute BookingTypeSelect bookingTypeSelect){
        System.out.println("Entered booking");
        return new ModelAndView("bookingTypeSelect" ,"bookingTypeSelect",bookingTypeSelect);
    }

**bookingLayout.jsp**

<div id="transportBookingLayout">
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="HeaderBookingTypeSelect"/></div>
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="BodyTransportSelector"/></div>
            <div><tiles:insertAttribute name="FooterTransportSelectorBooking"/></div>
</div>
```